# Palatino italics relatively small in body text?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, mathpazo, italic

I'm using Palatino (`\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`) as the main font for my thesis, and it occurred to me that italic (and possibly also bold) body texts are somewhat smaller than the '`\normalsize\normalfont`' texts.

Here is an image to illustrate the phenomenon:

[image: image illustrating the phenomenon]

Is this default Palatino behavior? Is there a way to particularly change the size of the italic and bold parts of the body text?

Comment: that is the default behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably something in your preamble messing things, because, by default, the italics of Palatino match the height of the roman:

[image: result of the code below]

Here's the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\parindent=0em
\begin{document}
\textit{is expected to integrate with current}\par
xt three propositions (\textit{A softw}\par
\textit{software architecture quality} \textbf{(P2)},\par
\textbf{(P4))} are also confirmed: en\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Philippe Actually the height of a capital upright B is 6.98pt, it's 6.96pt for the italic B, it's 6.86pt for the boldface B. The x-height is 4.69pt (roman), 4.82pt (italic) and 4.71pt (bold). And the italic lowercase letters are noticeably *higher* than the upright ones. The global font size shouldn't make any difference, because these fonts are scaled.

Comment: @Philippe The figures are slightly different when a T1 encoded font is used: 6.93pt, 6.935pt, 6.705 for the B; the x-heights don't change.

Comment: @egreg: You can't judge this kind of things with individual letter height (and the measures should be made in a font editing software like fontforge, sometimes TeX metrics are different). You must absolutely print a text sample with mixed words in roman, bold and italic and use your eye as sole judge. Doing this, the thing which is really amiss is all caps bold text among all caps roman text. Generally, bold must be slightly taller than roman to seem the same height, but it's font dependent. Here, of course, dbaw's problem is not something as subtle as that.

Comment: @Philippe: the printout confirms the figures. The boldface font is slightly smaller, but one should note that it's not in the original design by Zapf.

Comment: I get the same output as Philippe which differs from the image of the question. Most notably the brace before the A shows that different sizes are used. I think a complete example and the log-file of the pdflatex run is necessary.

Comment: OK, but where to look? Are there any specific commands or packages that could cause this change in font size?

Comment: Could the difference be caused by the use of `\emph{}` instead of `\textit{}`? Is there a way to particularly scale emphasized texts?

Comment: @dbaw: I don't know of any packages which would do that, and `\emph` normally doesn't change size. You should do as Ulrike suggested and edit your question to provide a complete example showing the problem. In a new tex file, copy your preamble from your document along with a phrase having both roman and italic in it. The resulting code should reproduce your problem, and you should try to take away the packages which are not relevant to the problem (trying them one by one) until the preamble is as short as possible but the problem still here.

Comment: I think I nailed down the cause of the problem: looks like the `alltt` environment was somehow changing the sizes of bold and italic fonts. Commenting the package out solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar (though not same) problem with `mathpazo` and `\textit`, so I'd just like to jot down my debug notes:

My problem was that what I expected to be italic, turned out to be bold - and sans serif (which I definitely didn't want)!

- First I tried inspecting `\textit` using `\show` and [`\pshow`](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ltxcmds) - went a bit tedious, didn't show much
- Then I realized that my problem occurs in `\paragraph*{\textit{Text ... }}` - hence it could be the `\paragraph*` that is the problem
- I try to inspect it with `\tracingall` - but since ["there’s no “off” command for \tracingall"](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-erroradvice), I use as recommended `\usepackage{`[`trace`](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/trace.html)`}` and place `\traceon`/`\traceoff` around the offending line
- Search for `sf` (for the sans serif) in the resulting .log, find this: 
   `\sectfont ->\normalcolor \sffamily \bfseries`

So, I starting tracing back what could have set the `\sectfont` to `\sffamily`, but since there's plenty of packages to go through, instead of finding which is the offending one, I simply "overloaded" (redefined) the `\sectfont` command before the offending line comes in:

```
....
% redefine sectfont to avoid setting sans-serif \sffamily
\def\sectfont{\normalcolor\bfseries}

\paragraph*{$\bullet$ "\textit{Text ... 
....
```

... and this got all working (at least for my problem).

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!